# Swift remove blank table view cells?

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift

This question is a bit different than similar questions where it's recommended to change the background color.

I currently only add a cell if the "domain" in the JSON reads as "youtube.com". Unfortunately, it will add a blank cell if otherwise denoted. How can I fix this?

[image: Code]

[image: Table View Data]

Comment: in your `numberOfRowsInSection` delegate, perform the filtering action of limiting the number of cells if it doesn't meet your requirements

Comment: Can you elaborate? I only want it to add a cell if the domain name req. is met. I am not sure how to achieve that.

Comment: You have the tableview delegate which tells the tableview how many total cells do you want. Lets say you said 10. But when you got data array of lets say 10 objects, only 7 met your requirements. Now you are populating only 7 cells, but you are returning 10 cells. Thats why you get 3 empty cells visible.

Comment: Remember `return cell` command at the end of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is still running, even if you don't populate those cells. Also, you have already told tableview that you want N-number of cells while in reality you want only N-X number of cells. You need to communicate that to your tableview

Comment: I realize I return cell at the end because the function needs a return object of a cell whether it contains my data or not. Hypothetically though, if I know I have 5 objects returning and I set the return of the numRowsSection func int return value to 5 with 7 total objects (2 empty), it crashes the program.

Comment: Why don't you filter your datasource array, and remove those objects whose domain is not youtube.com ? This way your datasource will not those have objects and there won't be empty cells.

Answer (score 0):

In `numberOfRowsInSection` you need to pass the right number of cells which you would later on display. I assume you are passing `redditEntry!["data"]!.count` here and then later on filtering for youtube.com domain in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

What you can do is have a filtered array from `redditEntry["data"]` and use this array as your table data source, so that both cells and number of cells match.